# Fisher information in Laplace approximation

Tags: fisher-information, laplace-approximation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with Probability Density Function (PDF) $f_X$ and $f_Y$, respectively. Upon observing $Y=y$, the log-posterior PDF is given by Bayes' rule in log form:

$$\ln f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\ln f_X(x)+\ln f_{Y|X}(y|x)-\ln f_Y(y)$$

Laplace approximation is based on a second-order Taylor-series approximation of the log-posterior PDF or equivalently the log-joint PDF $f(x)=\ln f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, resulting in a Gaussian PDF with mean equal to the Maximum A Poseriori (MAP) estimate $x^*$ and precision equal to the negative Hessian of the log-joint PDF at the MAP estimate $-H(f)(x^*)$, which [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_approximation) calls the observed Fisher information. However, as explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observed_information), the observed Fisher information is originally defined as the negative Hessian of the log-likelihood, so it must refer to the alternative definition by Gelman et al. (2014), which is based on the log-posterior or equivalently the log-joint.

Since the expected information is used as an approximation to the observed information in practice (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14806)), I would like to know the properties of the expected information according to this alternative definition. Let $p(x)=\ln f_X(x)$, $L(x)=\ln f_{Y|X}(Y|x)$ and $F(x)=\ln f_{X,Y}(x,Y)$ so that $F(x)=p(x)+L(x)$. With the original definition, we have $\mathbf E[-H(L)(x^*)]=\mathbf E[\nabla L(x^*)(\nabla L(x^*))^T]$. With the alternative definition, do we have $\mathbf E[-H(F)(x^*)]=\mathbf E[\nabla F(x^*)(\nabla F(x^*))^T]$?

We have

$$
\mathbf E[-H(F)(x^*)]=\mathbf E[-H(p)(x^*)]+\mathbf E[-H(L)(x^*)]
$$

and

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf E[\nabla F(x^*)(\nabla F(x^*))^T]
&=\mathbf E[(\nabla p(x^*)+\nabla L(x^*))(\nabla p(x^*)+\nabla L(x^*))^T]\\
&=\mathbf E[\nabla p(x^*)(\nabla p(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[\nabla p(x^*)(\nabla L(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[\nabla L(x^*)(\nabla p(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[\nabla L(x^*)(\nabla L(x^*))^T]\\
&=\mathbf E[\nabla p(x^*)(\nabla p(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[\nabla p(x^*)(\nabla L(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[\nabla L(x^*)(\nabla p(x^*))^T]+\mathbf E[-H(L)(x^*)]
\end{aligned}
$$

If the first three terms in the latter are equivalent to the first term in the former, then the equality can be established. But are they equivalent?